# Django : FOREIGN KEY constraint failed on delete, but I don't have any Foreign Key on my model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Here is my model which objects I can't delete :

```
class Broker(models.Model):
    code =              models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    name =              models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    email =             models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    city =              models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    address =           models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    postal_code =       models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, blank=True)
    brokerage =         models.FloatField(default=0.00)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'Broker'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Brokers'
         ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Here is what creates my error (he occurs on the line where I make rem.delete()):

```
if request.POST.get('action') == 'remove_element_selected':
    element_selected = request.POST.getlist('element_selected[]')
    for element_id in element_selected:
        rem = Broker.objects.get(id=element_id)
        rem.delete()
    return JsonResponse({})
```

And here is my error :

```
Internal Server Error: /brokers/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 67, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lucas/Desktop/myapp/app/views/views.py", line 636, in brokers
    rem.delete()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in delete
    return collector.delete()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 306, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Between, I'm using Django 2.1.15 and python 3.7.9

Also, I removed all the objects that was link in foreign key with my broker model.

Comment: Is this possible for us to see all Broker's relationships?

Comment: There is two relationships that I setted up like that : `broker = models.ForeignKey(Broker, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)`

Comment: Without knowing further details, there must be at least one record that is still related to Broker without on_delete. Or maybe, your migrations are not up-to-date?